# SharePoint Online是否可針對網站設定DisableCustomAppAuthentication 值

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-addin, administration, azure-ad

SharePoint Online是否可針對網站設定DisableCustomAppAuthentication 值，

例如：

Set-SPOSite -Identity https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxx -DisableCustomAppAuthentication $false

還是只能針對整個Tenant ，Set-SPOTenant -DisableCustomAppAuthentication $false

Answer (score 0):

`-DisableCustomAppAuthentication` is a tenant level setting. This parameter is available only with `Set-SPOTenant` cmdlet.

You can find more information in below documentations:

1. [Set-SPOTenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/set-spotenant?view=sharepoint-ps)
2. [Granting access using SharePoint App-Only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs)

**Related read**: [Connect to SharePoint Online from our console application when the "DisableCustomAppAuthentication is set to true"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/302076/connect-to-sharepoint-online-from-our-console-application-when-the-disablecusto/302108#302108)